# Mock doesn't work during chai.request api test

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, mocking, chai, web-api-testing

I have problem with API tests because when I am mocking something it is mocked everywhere except inside of chai.request method. I was checking all names and path a few times

```
chai.use(chaiHttp);

describe("Schedule API Routes", () => {
    let scheduleRepositoryStubForLessonPlan: SinonStub;
    let scheduleRepositoryStubForSession: SinonStub;

    beforeEach(() => {
        scheduleRepositoryStubForLessonPlan = stub(ScheduleRepository.prototype, "getStudentLessonPlan");
        scheduleRepositoryStubForSession = stub(ScheduleRepository.prototype, "getAccountIdAndSessionStatus");
    });

    afterEach(() => {
        scheduleRepositoryStubForLessonPlan.restore();
    });

    it("Should return 200 - student schedule", (done) => {
        const fakeRowSession = [
            {
                isExpired: true,
                accountType: "STUDENT",
                accountId: 123,
            },
        ];

        scheduleRepositoryStubForSession.resolves(fakeRowSession);

        const fakeRowLessonPlan = [

        ];

        scheduleRepositoryStubForLessonPlan.resolves(fakeRowLessonPlan);

        const sRep = new ScheduleRepository();
        const result = sRep.getAccountIdAndSessionStatus("test");
        console.log(result);

        chai.request(app)
            .get("/schedule?from=2023-05-22&to=2023-05-27")
            .set("Cookie", "test=x5rup8koxga2lr53e7uljg5ifasapa3go1jgl2g55huu4v0ihq8an1ueavb8rxh")
            .set("user-type", "student")
            .end((err, res) => {
                res.body.should.be.an("object");
                res.should.have.status(200);
                done();
            });
    });
});
```

Maybe somebody know how to mock function in API tests

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are facing might be due to the lifecycle of your application and the lifecycle of your tests not aligning properly. This often happens when you stub a method after your app has already been created and started. The reason is that your routes might have been created before the Sinon stub was in place, meaning the original function was used, not the stub.

Here's a common pattern for resolving this:

1. Create a factory function for your app. This function will start your app and it's invoked at the start of each test.
2. Invoke this factory function in your test's `beforeEach` hook.
3. Place your stubs before invoking the factory function.

Here's an example of what your test might look like with this pattern:

```js
const { expect } = require("chai");
const sinon = require("sinon");
const chai = require("chai");
const chaiHttp = require("chai-http");
chai.use(chaiHttp);

const ScheduleRepository = require("path-to-your-schedule-repository");
const appFactory = require("path-to-your-app-factory");

describe("Schedule API Routes", () => {
    let app; 
    let scheduleRepositoryStubForLessonPlan;
    let scheduleRepositoryStubForSession;

    beforeEach(() => {
        scheduleRepositoryStubForLessonPlan = sinon.stub(ScheduleRepository.prototype, "getStudentLessonPlan");
        scheduleRepositoryStubForSession = sinon.stub(ScheduleRepository.prototype, "getAccountIdAndSessionStatus");
        
        // Stubs are in place, now start the app
        app = appFactory();
    });

    afterEach(() => {
        scheduleRepositoryStubForLessonPlan.restore();
        scheduleRepositoryStubForSession.restore();
    });

    it("Should return 200 - student schedule", (done) => {
        const fakeRowSession = [
            {
                isExpired: true,
                accountType: "STUDENT",
                accountId: 123,
            },
        ];

        scheduleRepositoryStubForSession.resolves(fakeRowSession);

        const fakeRowLessonPlan = [

        ];

        scheduleRepositoryStubForLessonPlan.resolves(fakeRowLessonPlan);

        const sRep = new ScheduleRepository();
        const result = sRep.getAccountIdAndSessionStatus("test");
        console.log(result);

        chai.request(app)
            .get("/schedule?from=2023-05-22&to=2023-05-27")
            .set("Cookie", "test=x5rup8koxga2lr53e7uljg5ifasapa3go1jgl2g55huu4v0ihq8an1ueavb8rxh")
            .set("user-type", "student")
            .end((err, res) => {
                expect(res).to.have.status(200);
                expect(res.body).to.be.an("object");
                done();
            });
    });
});
```

You'll need to create an `appFactory` function that sets up your Express app. This function should be in the same module as where you define your app, and should export it. Here is an example of what it could look like:

```js
// ... other requires ...

const ScheduleRepository = require("path-to-your-schedule-repository");

// define your app here
const app = express();

// ... app setup ...

// now export a factory function that creates and returns your app
module.exports = function appFactory() {
    app.use("/schedule", scheduleRouter(ScheduleRepository));
    // ... any other routes ...

    return app;
};
```

In the `appFactory`, you'd provide any services that your routes need, such as repositories, databases, etc.